# Automatically Removing a PowerShell Job when it has finished (asynchronously)

Tags: powershell, jobs, powershell-cmdlet

I have a PowerShell cmdlet which I use to simplify connecting to another computer with RDP.

Within that cmdlet I run do the following:

```
    if ($null -ne $Username -and $null -ne $Password) {
        Start-Process -FilePath "cmdkey.exe" -ArgumentList @("/generic:`"TERMSRV/$ComputerName`"", "/user:`"$Username`"", "/pass:`"$Password`"") -WindowStyle Hidden
    }

    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        param($InstallPath, $ComputerName, $Port, $Username, $Password)

        $arguments = @("`"$(Join-Path $InstallPath '\Support Files\MSTSC\Default.rdp')`"")
        if ($null -ne $Port) {
            $arguments += "/v:`"$($ComputerName):$($Port)`""
        } else {
            $arguments += "/v:`"$($ComputerName)`""
        }

        Start-Process -FilePath "mstsc.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait

        if ($null -ne $Username -and $null -ne $Password) {
            Start-Process -FilePath "cmdkey.exe" -ArgumentList @("/delete:`"TERMSRV/$ComputerName`"") -WindowStyle Hidden
        }
    } -ArgumentList @($InstallPath, $ComputerName, $Port, $Username, $Password)
```

As you can see I add the credentials used to connect to the remote machine, then start a job which executes mstsc.exe, waits for it to finish then removes the credentials.

The problem is I have to wait for mstsc to close before deleting the credentials, as otherwise they get removed before mstsc has a chance to establish the connection and I want this cmdlet to be self contained - returning control immediately to the users command prompt so I can run other commands while I am also using the RDP session which means I can't wait for the job to finish as that mean I am stuck waiting until I disconnect from the remote session:

```
| Wait-Job | Remove-Job
```

What I want to do is to be able to Remove-Job once it has completed, perhaps using some kind of callback so I don't have to manually run another command to clean up the Job once I log out of the RDP session and the Job isn't left in a Completed state (which is what I am currently doing but obviously this isn't 'clean).

For the full cmdlet you can see it here for more context:

https://github.com/paulmarsy/Console/blob/master/AdvancedPowerShellConsole/Exports/Functions/Connect-Remote.ps1

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very old question... You can use `Register-ObjectEvent` to clean up after jobs. Jobs have a `StateChanged` event that has an `EventSubscriber` parameter passed to it containing details of the event and the source job.

Here's an example. Once the job completes the callback will remove both itself and the source job.

```
$job = Start-Job { Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 }
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $job -EventName StateChanged -Action {
    Unregister-Event $EventSubscriber.SourceIdentifier
    Remove-Job $EventSubscriber.SourceIdentifier
    Remove-Job -Id $EventSubscriber.SourceObject.Id
} | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1):

So register a scheduledjob to run in 5 minutes that will remove the completed job. I am pretty sure that you can do something like:

```
Register-ScheduledJob -ScriptBlock {param($computername); Wait-Job -Name $ComputerName|remove-job} -Trigger @{Frequency="Once";At=(get-date).AddMinutes(5).ToString("h:MM tt")} -argumentlist $computername
```

Then just give your connection a name when you do your Start-Job by appending `-Name $ComputerName` to the end of the command. That way 5 minutes after you launch it a scheduled task kicks off that finds and clears out that job by name.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I tried it but then this job is on the Get-Job/Get-EventSubscriber list waiting to be cleaned up after finishing so still have the same problem. The approach I have taken for now is to create a new PowerShell host ( https://github.com/paulmarsy/Console/tree/master/AdvancedPowerShellConsole/Exports/Functions/Threading ), adding the cleanup code there and starting it with BeginInvoke. It isn't perfect as it uses more resources and I don't call EndInvoke currently (otherwise it waits for it to complete) but hope to fix it using the InvocationStateChanged event.